# Android: Uploading photos from SD Card to Facebook Wall

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to upload pictures from my SD Card to my facebook account and still got no luck.
I'm not getting any errors but the pictures I'm trying to upload are not appearing on my wall.
Here's my code (full code of the Main Class):

```
import com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner;
import com.facebook.android.DialogError;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook;
import com.facebook.android.FacebookError;
import com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner.RequestListener;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook.DialogListener;

public class Gallery extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "Gallery";
    // Constants
    private static final int UPDATE_GRID_VIEW = 0;
    // References to our images
    private ArrayList<Uri> picUri = new ArrayList<Uri>();
    private ArrayList<String> picName = new ArrayList<String>();
    private GridView mGridview;
    private ImageAdapter mImageAdapter;
    // For FaceBook
    private Facebook facebook;
    private String fb_AppId = "MY_APP_ID";

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog progressD;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.gallery);
        initializeViews();
        initFacebook();
        authorizeFbUser();
    }

    public void initializeViews(){
        PictureListThread picThread = new PictureListThread();
        picThread.start();

        mImageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
        mGridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gallery_gridview);
        mGridview.setAdapter(mImageAdapter);
        mGridview.setOnItemClickListener(mOnItemClickListener);
    }

    // Facebook Methods and Classes
    public void initFacebook(){
        facebook = new Facebook(fb_AppId);

    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    public void authorizeFbUser(){
        facebook.authorize(this, new String[] { "email", "read_stream" },
            new DialogListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "******************* FACEBOOK::authorize::onComplete *******************");
                }

                @Override
                public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "******************* FACEBOOK::authorize::onFacebookError *******************");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(DialogError e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "******************* FACEBOOK::authorize::onError *******************");
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "******************* FACEBOOK::authorize::onCancel *******************");
                }
        });
    }

    public class mRequestListener implements RequestListener{

        @Override
        public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e, Object state) {
            Log.d(TAG, "******************* FACEBOOK::onMalformedURLException *******************");
        }

        @Override
        public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
            Log.d(TAG, "******************* FACEBOOK::onIOException *******************");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e, Object state) {
            Log.d(TAG, "******************* FACEBOOK::onFileNotFoundException *******************");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
            Log.d(TAG, "******************* FACEBOOK::onFacebookError *******************");
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
            Log.d(TAG, "******************* FACEBOOK::onComplete *******************");
        }

    }
    // Methods

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            if(msg.what == UPDATE_GRID_VIEW) {
                mImageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } 
        }
    };

    // Inner Classes

    private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Log.d(TAG,"[][][][][][][][][][]-------------> PATH: "+picUri.get(position).toString());
            byte[] data = null;
            Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picUri.get(position).toString());
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bi.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
            data = baos.toByteArray();
            Log.d(TAG,"[][][][][][][][][][]-------------> DATA: "+data);

            Bundle param = new Bundle();
            param.putString("method", "photos.upload");
            param.putString("message", picName.get(position));
            param.putByteArray("picture", data);

            AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
            mAsyncRunner.request("me/photos", param, "POST", new mRequestListener(), null);



            Log.d(TAG,"[][][][][][][][][][]-------------> Gallery::mOnItemClickListener END!");
        }
    };

    private class PictureListThread extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d(TAG, "******************* PictureListThread::run() STARTED! *******************");;   
            System.gc();
            String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE};
            Cursor picturecursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    proj, null, null, MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE);

            if (picturecursor == null)
                return;

            if (!picturecursor.moveToFirst())
                return;

            do { 
                String picTitle = picturecursor.getString(picturecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE));
                if(picTitle.contains("KEYWORD")){
                    picName.add(picTitle);
                    picUri.add(Uri.parse(picturecursor.getString(picturecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA))));
                    Log.d(TAG,"[][][][][][][][][][]-------------> PICTURE ADDED: "+picTitle);   
                    mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(UPDATE_GRID_VIEW);
                }
            } while (picturecursor.moveToNext());

        }

    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context mContext;

        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return picUri.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imageView;
            if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
                imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(150, 100));
                imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
            } else {
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }

            imageView.setImageURI(picUri.get(position));
            return imageView;
        }


    }

}
```

My

> mRequestListener()::onComplete()

is being called with no errors and so I'm wondering why the pictures are not displaying on my wall.

Am I missing something here?

Please help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put this line.

```
mAsyncRunner.request("me/photos", param, "POST", new mRequestListener(), null);
```

instead of

```
mAsyncRunner.request(null, param, "POST", new mRequestListener(), null);
```

and check photo will appear on wall or not?

add **"publish_stream"** in permission..

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've tried that as well but unfortunately still got no luck. Maybe there something wrong with the facebook API I have in my application. Actualy, I edited the Util.java of the facebook package to fix the ClassCast Exception. I change the line "if (params.getByteArray(key) != null) {" to "if (params.get(key) instanceof byte[]) {". Do you think this affects the upload process?

Comment: i think it will affected and i also got that error ***ClassCastException* but my photo is uploading with this error so remove your edited and check , dear

Comment: Still having the same error..:( If I'm not mistaken, we need to use facebook SSO right? I'm using the facebook.authorize() on start of my application but I noticed that facebook.authorize()::onComplete() was not called although I'm being prompted to log-in and authorize my app to access my basic information. Then I click on "Allow". But it seems to be the onComplete() is not being called. Do you think this is the reason?

Comment: just change this line and check  facebook.authorize(**Gallery.this**, new String[] { "email", "read_stream" },                  and replace this code **facebook.request("me/photos",param,"POST");** for uploading photo instead of **AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
            mAsyncRunner.request("me/photos", param, "POST", new mRequestListener(), null);**

Comment: still no luck.. :( I think it is because of the `response` string: `{"error":{"type":"Exception","message":"Unsupported method, photos.upload"}}`. I got this on the onComplete of my RequestListener when I used the AsyncFacebookRunner.

Comment: just change this line and check facebook.authorize(Gallery.this, new String[] { "email", "read_stream" }, and replace this code facebook.request("me/photos",param,"POST"); for uploading photo instead of AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook); mAsyncRunner.request("me/photos", param, "POST", new mRequestListener(), null);  and add permission of **publish_stream** and plz dont change rest thing and check means remove "photos.upload"

Comment: @Erick let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2011/discussion-between-capdroid-and-erick)

Comment: It's ok now! I used the AsyncFacebookRunner. The problem is on the authorization, I've uninstalled the facebook.apk to complete the authorization and the pictures are now uploading! Thanks so much for your help! +1 on your answer!

Comment: I know its out of the topic but I would like to ask you if it is possible to upload videos? I use `param.putByteArray("video", data); mAsyncRunner.request("me/videos", param, "POST", new fbRequestListener(), null);` but I just receive a response string `{"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"(#2) Service temporarily unavailable"}}`. Do you have any idea with this?

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken, your Bundle param is missing "method" property. Try adding:

```
param.putString("method", "photos.upload");
```

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I think I accidentally removed that line. I already have that from the beginning. Thanks for your time. :)

Comment: How about this?
  `facebook.authorize(this, new String[] { "email", "read_stream" },`

You should request "publish_stream" permission for uploading photos. So try adding "publish_stream" to the end of your String array.

Comment: change "read_stream" to "publish_stream" right? Still no luck.. :(

Comment: What does your `response` String contain? Have you tried decoding data array back to an image, to check if it decodes correctly?

Comment: Now that you've mentioned it, I tried to check it and here's the response: {"error":{"type":"Exception","message":"Unsupported method, photos.upload"}}

Comment: photos.upload is a REST API method. try removing that line :)

Comment: it's ok now. i need to make the authorization process finish by removing the facebook.apk.. Thanks! +1 for you!