# How to upload image from sdcard to facebook wall?

Tags: android

I want upload image from sdcard to facebook. I try lot for it, but I can't get success. What should I do?

my code is:

```
<tr>
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("message", "Uploaded on " + now());
params.putByteArray("picture", bytes); //bytes contains photo bytes, no problem here
asyncRunner.request("me/photos", params, "POST", new PostPhotoRequestListener(), null);
</tr>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Uploading photos from SD Card to Facebook Wall](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894133/android-uploading-photos-from-sd-card-to-facebook-wall)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copied the solution from this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658877/how-to-upload-image-on-facebook-image-store-in-sdcard-in-android-2-1).
You should use Facebook API http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#android. And then use this code:

```
 byte[] data = null;
 try {
     FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(PATH_TO_FILE);
     Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
     ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     bi.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
     data = baos.toByteArray();  
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
     e.printStackTrace();
     Log.d("onCreate", "debug error  e = " + e.toString());
  }     

     Bundle params = new Bundle(); 
     params.putString("method", "photos.upload");  
     params.putByteArray("picture", data);

     Facebook facebook = new Facebook(FACEBOOK_APP_ID);
     AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
     mAsyncRunner.request(null, params, "POST", new RequestListener() {

        public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e, Object state) {
            Log.d("request RequestListener", "debug onMalformedURLException");
        }

        public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
            Log.d("request RequestListener", "debug onIOException");
        }

        public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e, Object state) {
            Log.d("request RequestListener", "debug onFileNotFoundException");
        }

        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
            Log.d("request RequestListener", "debug onFacebookError");
        }

        public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
             Log.d("request RequestListener", "debug onComplete");
        }
     }, null);
```

Be sure you application has permission to internet and sdcard reading

Answer (score 0):

I have answered a similar question on SO here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10561377/450534

```
protected void uploadPhoto() {
    if (!Utility.mFacebook.isSessionValid()) {
        Util.showAlert(this, "Warning", "You must first log in.");
    } else {
        if (targetUri != null) {
            Bundle params = new Bundle();
            try {
                params.putByteArray("photo", Utility.scaleImage(getApplicationContext(), targetUri));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            params.putString("caption", txtPhotoCaption.getText().toString());
            Utility.mAsyncRunner.request( "replace this with your ID"+ "/photos&access_token=" + Utility.mFacebook.getAccessToken(), 
                    params, "POST", new PhotoUploadListener(), null);
            txtPhotoCaption.setText("");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Photo uploaded successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            this.finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Please note, that I am using the same method as used in the sample app. Without getting into the pros or cons of scaling or not scaling the image. The "**caption**" attribute is being pulled from an EditText. And the actual image is in the field "**targetUri**", which is declared as a global variable. It's fetching the image using the default Gallery on the device. For the sake of completeness, this is the code to grab the image from the default Gallery app. (this prompts the user to select the app)

```
btnAddPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
        });
```

And it is processed in the `onActivityResult()` here:

**NOTE**: *I am also setting the selected image in an ImageView as a preview to the logged in user*

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)    {
            targetUri = data.getData();
            Log.e("IMG URI", targetUri.toString());
            try {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(targetUri));
                try {
                    Utility.scaleImage(getApplicationContext(), targetUri);
                    imgDisplaySelectedImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

The answer in the link mentioned is for uploading a photo to a *friends* wall. But the same code with my ID instead of the friends ID does essentially the same task as you want. Hope this helps you as well.

EDIT: In the first piece of code, here ***replace this with your ID***, you can also make a call to `"me/photos&access_token="`. The rest remain the same.